# QTP - Is there any relevance in setting WPF objects to nothing from the GC perspective?

Tags: c#, wpf, garbage-collection, qtp, hp-uft

I have a long running QTP test which does a bunch of UI actions on my WPF application. I started off creating the script by explicitly invoking the WPF objects. Like so:

```
WpfWindow("").WpfButton.Click
WpfWindow("").WpfList.Select 1
```

I wanted to know if I should change this to

```
Set myWindow = WpfWindow("")
myWindow.WpfButton.Click
myWindow.WpfList.Select 1
Set myWindow = NOTHING
```

Does version (1) prevent GC because Qtp may be holding references to the objects? Does version (2) avoid that problem?

Update: The same long running script seems to release memory or handle memory references better in UFT 11.53. I was using Qtp11 before.

Comment: Why would you care? What do you want to achieve/are you wondering about, really? Is this a case of premature optimization :-9 ?

Comment: This question was based on an observation where I noticed a memory leak in my app *only* when running UI tests with Qtp11. No question of "premature optimisation".

Answer (score 0):

You have two items at play here... in version 1, you're referring to the Test Object references to WPF-based objects that QTP uses for playback.  In version 2, you still have those but you've added local variables that are now referencing those test objects.

QTP/UFT was architected in such a way that when you reference a test object the way you did in version 1, it will actually perform a new lookup.  Consider, for instance, that you had an extra button click, but it was the same button being clicked twice in a row:

```
WpfWindow("MyWindow").WpfButton("OK").Click
WpfWindow("MyWindow").WpfButton("OK").Click
```

This may look like you're pressing the same UI element twice in a row, but that's not certain.  After you click "OK" the first time, the UI could present a different window that also had an "OK" button with the same identification properties.  In this case, the second click operation would recognize and click the new "OK" button.

In version 2 of your code, you've altered this behavior because you're beginning to cache an object reference.  This can be good and bad.  If you know the object is not going to change on the screen, that's good.  If the element changes and you have already cached it, you will run into issues.  So if the above logic were adjusted to this:

```
Set btn = WpfWindow("MyWindow").WpfButton("OK")
btn.Click
btn.Click
Set btn = Nothing
```

You are now caching the lookup that was performed for the first "OK" button.  If clicking that button the first time causes the UI to change, the second click could cause problems without you refreshing the test object (which causes it to re-identify the object).

So to go back to your original question, QTP/UFT should not be creating references to your UI objects that would prevent garbage collection.  If you cache a test object like in version 2, you should always set it to Nothing when you're done.  That applies universally to all object-based variable assignments in VBScript.  The scripting engine should clear memory when the variable goes out of scope, but it's good practice to force it just in case.

Comment: Thank you for the code suggestions. On the 2nd part would you know how I can verify your statement? I'm unsure of what logic, at the object reference level, the .NET GC uses to free up memory. And how UFT/Qtp aligns with that logic.

Comment: The only way I can think to verify it would be to write a simple WPF-based application where you could check the GC status of UI objects after disposing of a view that was previously referenced by QTP/UFT.

Comment: "The scripting engine should clear memory when the variable goes out of scope, but it's good practice to force it just in case." It still is unclear why this would be good practice. Either the engine does it, or not. If it does, the assignment is useless. If it doesn´t, it´s an engine bug

Comment: The only place where the Nothing assignments make sense is in the OLE/COM/DCOM world where it is crucial to control the exact moment where there are no further references to object instances. There, you might need to set to nothing so the instance is reference-free before the variable holding the reference goes out of scope.

Comment: I say "good practice" because most people don't put much thought into the inner workings of the engine.  You'll never go wrong if you make it a habit to set object-based variables to Nothing when you're done with them.  Forget to do it and you're placing your faith in the engine handling it.